# getting symbols in string Android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

in ndk i want to convert some ascii values to string.I am getting the result but there is some symbols after the string

this is the answer i am getting

sint#j8na8̀

My code is

```
    jstring Java_com_magsonwink_utils_security_En_invokeNativeFunction(
    JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {

int i = 0;

int a[3]= {
        115,
        105,
        110,
};
char b[3];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        b[i] = (char) a[i];

    }
 jstring result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, b);

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to null-terminate the string?
Try

```
jstring Java_com_magsonwink_utils_security_En_invokeNativeFunction(
    JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {

   int i = 0;

   int a[3]= {
        115,
        105,
        110,
   };
   char b[4];
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        b[i] = (char) a[i];

    }
   b[3] = 0;
   jstring result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, b);

   return result;
}
```